# Add custom field in Joomla 1.6 Registration

Tags: joomla

I want to insert extra fields in Joomla 1.6 registration page like phone no, current year of education ("FE", "SE", "TE", "BE") etc.
I don't want to use Community plugin, I want to hack the core files in Joomla to do this and add the required information to jos_user table.

I've see tutorials for this for 1.5 but no such tutorial for 1.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't hack core. Clone the `plugins/user/profile/` plugin with a different name (studentprofile, etc...). Except for the `profiles` folder, change the names from `profile` to the new one wherever you see it. Assuming `studentprofile` as the name, after you've installed the clone, edit the file `plugins/user/studentprofile/profiles/profile.xml`. This is where you can add your custom fields. After the field is enabled, edit the `plugins/user/studentprofile/studentprofile.xml` and `studentprofile.php` to match the new fields. Then enable the plugin.

Comment: i did this, but i cannot find this new plugin in the plugin field. The old one shows perfectly.

Comment: Did you install the new plugin through the installer?

Comment: You have to install it, as if it was from internet

Comment: I made a folder with the files plugins/user/studentprofile/profiles/profile.xml and other files.        Then I created a zip of the folder and tried to install it, but i get the following error. JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist /home/inventik/public_html/vcet/tmp/install_4e3035d662996/profile5/index.html

Comment: Are you able to install any other extensions? It sounds like your `tmp` folder might not be writable.

Comment: @PriteshDesai : the error is because your zip which contains the plugin does not include an index.html file, but the manifest (the .xml file) lists it. Just add the index.html file and you should be fine.

Comment: The plugin can be "registered" using Discover feature in backend.