# Custom Joomla Registration Form and Profile

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6, joomla-template

I want to create a custom Joomla registration form and a profile to show the information saved. For this I followed the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809531/add-custom-field-in-joomla-1-6-registration) thread. I have cloned and changed the files of the user profile plugin. Now the problem is that the edited profile form is not displayed after I have enabled the plugin. I have a login link on my site, which on success redirects to a profile display page after that. When I click edit on the profile display page, the edit profile form is still the same old one and it is located at **profile?layout=edit**. All it has is:

- Name
- Username
- Password
- Confirm Password
- Email
- Confirm Email
- Basic Settings

Why is this not working. The installation was also fine.

Is this even the right way of doing this.

Please help with this. I appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the right way of doing things. Just some double-checks: you edited the files in the plugin and installed it without issue? When you go to the plugin manager in the admin area it shows up (separately to the core plugin)? And you've enabled the plugin there?

Comment: Perhaps disabling the core profile plugin, and leaving yours enabled is the key there - that's a way you could try it without adjusting anything else.

If you've done that, iss there a module or component that is handling the users profile that was added (i.e. not a core joomla component)?  If so, then you'll have to dive into that component most likely - make a template override - and edit that link to point to your plugin if for some reason it's pointing to the core plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with Community Builder. It has amazing search features.

Answer (score 1):

See original Joomla docs on how to add a profile plugin in Joomla 1.6
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin